# SSL verification problem in crawling data through websocket

Tags: python, ssl, websocket

I have problems crawling data through websocket. When I create a connection, it doesn't work whether you choose different versions of SSL or turn off authentication

```
    ws = websocket.create_connection(
            url='wss://***',
            timeout=60,
            # header=header,
            # subprotocols=["binary", "base64"],
            sslopt={
                "cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE,
                # "check_hostname": False,
                "ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv2

            }
        )
```

This is the error that I gave:

```
error message: The remote host forced an existing connection to be closed.
```

Qhen ssl_version is `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3`, the error is:

```
error message:[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:646).
```

About the settings I tried:
Setting `cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE` is useless in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know what is meant by crawling site using websocket but your cryptography is very outdated...

SSL 2.0 was deprecated in 2011: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#SSL_1.0,_2.0,_and_3.0

Any modern site should be configured to reject any weak cryptography protocols, maybe that is causing your errors.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't describe it clearly. 
I want to crawl data by connecting to the WSS of the target website.I don't have an SSL certificate and want to bypass authentication.
Because using selenium is too unstable and cumbersome

Comment: You probably recieve some live data as json? This should not make a difference SSL layer is pretty much same. Try above...

Comment: Yes, I will try more. 
Thank you for the link, I think I can learn a lot